# Why do I get an error in react regarding my background-image in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have no idea why I'm getting this error in my react project. I fixed the URL path and renamed them properly but for some reasons, I keep getting the same error.

This is my CSS:

```
  background-image: url("../assets/img/header-bg.jpg");
```

and the other image is

```
  background-image: url("../assets/img/map-image.png");
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

if the image doesn't show then the error is this

> Error: Can't resolve '../assets/img/header-bg.jpg' in 'C:\Users\bryan\start-bootstrap\src\assets\css'

the pathway of my images and CSS is:

```
src > assets > img > header-bg.jpg,map-image.png
```

[image]

My assets folder also has my CSS folder with my styles which includes bootstrap:

```
src > assets > css > style.css
```

Answer (score 2):

Its probably because the Node.js module is searching for `/assets/assets/img/map-image.png` (it's searching from CSS), that's why your code isn't working, just remove `/assets` from the property.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm learning react and was stuck on this part. Just wondering why is Node.js searching assets twice?